# Wayland in Kubuntu 17.10

Tags: kubuntu, 17.10, wayland

I was expecting that Kubuntu 17.10 would use Wayland by default (just like Ubuntu 17.10) or that it would at least be possible to select it from the login screen. This does not seem to be the case, unfortunately.

```
$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11
```

Can anyone point me to the steps to set up Wayland on Kubuntu 17.10?

Comment: Looked at the 17.04 question(s) but it did not work on 17.10. Wayland support is changing quickly, so I think an answer specifically for 17.10 is useful.

Comment: the accepted answer in the linked post states "Support for running a full Plasma session on Wayland is still in it's early stages." Thus, it may not be possible. It also states that Plasma >=5.4 is needed.

Comment: It's at version 5.10.5 in Kubuntu 17.10...

Comment: It is not really possible to write an answer specific to a version of Ubuntu as there are too many variables, kernel version (drivers), wayland version, plasma version, and graphics card, and rapid development. The general procedure is going to be the same in all cases at the moment, KDE defaults to X and run `startplasmacompositor`.  "support" and "development" change the chances of success, not the procedure for how to start KDE on wayland.

Comment: @chrisvdb: I added an answer specific to Kubuntu 17.10 to the other question. It isn't as complicated as the accepted answer makes it sound.